# quick implementation of prim algorithm

Tags: c++, graph-algorithm

learning graph theory in c++ here.
Sorry for the C-style codes.
I got an segmentation fault of my codes. I understand the meaning of it but have not learnt how to debug with IDE yet.
However I feel the bug is somewhere in my `spanningtree()` function. Could anyone point me out what could went wrong? The program is meant to print out the cost matrix, the minimum distance path and the total path cost. However, it exited after inputting.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class prims
{
private:
    int no_of_edges, no_of_nodes;
    int graph[10][10],visited[10],mindist[10];
public:
    void input();
    void output();
    void spanningtree();

    prims()
    {
        no_of_edges = no_of_nodes = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            //assign visited minimum distance array to 0
            visited[i] = mindist[i] = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j<10; j++)
            {
                graph[i][j] = 0;
            }

        }
    }
};

void prims::input()
{
    int vertex1, vertex2, cost;
    cout << "Enter no_of_nodes  ";
    cin >> no_of_nodes;
    cout << "Enter the no_of_edges  ";
    cin >> no_of_edges;
    for (int i = 0; i< no_of_edges; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter vertex1   ";
        cin >> vertex1;
        cout << "Enter vertex2   ";
        cin >> vertex2;
        cout << "Enter the cost of " << vertex1 << " and " << vertex2 << "  ";
        cin >> cost;
        graph[vertex1][vertex2]=graph[vertex2][vertex1]=cost;
    }
}

void prims::output()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < no_of_nodes; i++)
    {
        cout << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j< no_of_nodes; j++)
        {
            cout.width(4);
            cout << graph[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void prims::spanningtree()
{
    int min = 9999, row, col, index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < no_of_nodes; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i; j < no_of_nodes; j++)
        {
            if(graph[i][j]<min&&graph[i][j]!=0)
            {
                min = graph[i][j];
                row = i;
                col = j;
            }
        }
    }
    visited[row]=visited[col]=1;
    mindist[index++]=min;

    for (int i = 0; i < no_of_nodes - 2; i++)
    {
       min = 9999;

        for (int j = 0; j < no_of_nodes; j++)
        {
            if(visited[j]==1)
            {
                for(int k = 0; j < no_of_nodes; k++)
                {
                    if(graph[j][k]<min&&graph[j][k]!=0 && visited[k]==0)
                    {
                        min = graph[j][k];
                        row = j;
                        col = k;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        mindist[index++]=min;
        visited[row]=visited[col]=1;
    }
    int total = 0;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Minimum distance path is ";
    for (int i=0; i < no_of_nodes-1; i++)
    {
        cout << " " << mindist[i] << " ";
        total = total + mindist[i];
    }
    cout << endl << "Total path cost is    " << total;
}




int main()
{
    prims obj;
    obj.input();
    obj.spanningtree();
    obj.output();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and [tour] and [example]. The purpose of this site is not to be a code-dump-debugging service, but rather a repository of interesting questions that might help future searchers. Not to be rude, but the best answer I have to "*have not learnt how to debug with IDE yet*" is "Learn how. Preferably now."

Comment: Links rot and when they do anything at the link is lost. If your question depends  too much on a link, and this question does, it will become useless. Godbolt I trust enough to visit, so I've copied your code over. I haven't inspected it closely, but it probably isn't a valid [mre].

Comment: "but have not learnt how to debug with IDE yet" Now is a good time to learn. Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some tips to get started.

Comment: Since your program takes input, we'd need you to supply the input that's causing the crash. Preferably you'd make a MRE and remove the input function and just replace that with static values that reproduce the error (among other slimming-down features).

Comment: Typo in your `for(int k = 0; j < no_of_nodes; k++)` for loop. The comparison should be `k < no_of_nodes`.

Comment: @JohnFilleau and others. Thank you for the suggestions from all. I am planning to learn asap how to debug in the IDE I have been using, Qt.

Answer (score 1):

Taking some credits from the helpful comments/answers. Here is my revised codes. The main issue was the typo in one of the loop `for(int k = 0; j < no_of_nodes; k++)`.

```
using namespace std;
class prims
{
private:
    int no_of_edges, no_of_nodes;
    int graph[10][10],visited[10],mindist[10];
public:
    void input();
    void output();
    void spanningtree();
    prims()
    {
        no_of_edges = no_of_nodes = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            //assign visited minimum distance array to 0
            visited[i] = mindist[i] = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j<10; j++)
            {
                graph[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
};
void prims::input()
{
    int vertex1, vertex2, cost;
    cout << "Enter no_of_nodes  ";
    cin >> no_of_nodes;
    cout << "Enter the no_of_edges  ";
    cin >> no_of_edges;
    for (int i = 0; i< no_of_edges; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter vertex1   ";
        cin >> vertex1;
        cout << "Enter vertex2   ";
        cin >> vertex2;
        cout << "Enter the cost of " << vertex1 << " and " << vertex2 << "  ";
        cin >> cost;
        graph[vertex1][vertex2]=graph[vertex2][vertex1]=cost;
    }
}
void prims::output()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < no_of_nodes; i++)
    {
        cout << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j< no_of_nodes; j++)
        {
            cout.width(4);
            cout << graph[i][j]<<" ";
        }
    }
}
void prims::spanningtree()
{
    int min = 9999, row, col, index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < no_of_nodes; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i; j < no_of_nodes; j++)
        {
            if(graph[i][j]<min&&graph[i][j]!=0)
            {
                min = graph[i][j];
                row = i;
                col = j;
            }
        }
    }
    visited[row]=visited[col]=1;
    mindist[index++]=min;
    for (int i = 0; i < no_of_nodes - 2; i++)
    {
       min = 9999;
        for (int j = 0; j < no_of_nodes; j++)
        {
            if(visited[j]==1)
            {
                for(int k = 0; k < no_of_nodes; k++)
                {
                    if(graph[j][k]<min&&graph[j][k]!=0 && visited[k]==0)
                    {
                        min = graph[j][k];
                        row = j;
                        col = k;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        mindist[index++]=min;
        visited[row]=visited[col]=1;
    }
    int total = 0;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Minimum distance path is ";
    for (int i=0; i < no_of_nodes-1; i++)
    {
        cout << " " << mindist[i] << " ";
        total = total + mindist[i];
    }
    cout << endl << "Total path cost is    " << total << endl;
}
int main()
{
    prims obj;
    obj.input();
    obj.spanningtree();
    obj.output();
   // return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your primary problem is not checking that indexes are in range (there is where c++ might help, but you can do it in c as well).  Primary debugging tool - print.  If you would print j and k before using them as array indexes you would solve your problem yourself